# To what surface is this figure homeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry

I suspect that the following surface is homeomorphic to one of genus 3, but I can't provide an explanation, I mean can't say why by cutting or deforming it, can someone help me with this please?

[image]

Comment: is not it from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8Rxep2Mkp8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed the surface of genus three. To see this, we can deform the vertical tube to the exterior of the surface so that you get sphere with the torus thing inside of it, in a connected sum with a torus. Then move the horizontal tube outside of the sphere to get what is clearly the connected sum of three tori.

[image]

The left figure is the first step, the right picture is the second step.

Comment: What is a sphere ball?

Comment: Thanks, let me continue checking :)

Comment: I meant the sphere (not really a sphere, just that portion of the surface which seems like a bounding sphere).

Comment: jaja right, I saw the same in the figure :) It is like a sphere for me  :)

Comment: then the second step is then the genus three surface right?

Comment: Yes, also called the connected sum of three tori.